# GeoFencing not working with Geolocator in Flutter

Tags: flutter, geofencing, flutter-packages, geolocator

I am getting this error while debug build my flutter app.
***Because easy_geofencing 0.2.0 depends on geolocator ^7.7.1 and no versions of easy_geofencing match >0.2.0 <0.3.0, easy_geofencing ^0.2.0 requires geolocator ^7.7.1.***

I am using **geolocator: ^9.0.2** and **easy_geofencing: ^0.2.0** packages from pub.dev.

Can someone please solve the problem.

Please help me!

I tried lowering the version of geolocator package to 7.7.1, but it was not helpful, as that version didn't contained the features I needed.

If anyone has faced similiar problem. Can you please help me out!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```yaml
  geolocator: ^7.7.1
  easy_geofencing: ^0.2.0
```

or let the flutter decide

```yaml
  geolocator: any
  easy_geofencing: any
```